# External drive corrupted or inaccessible in Windows XP, but works on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-xp, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Today I connected my Western Digital 1 TB HDD to my Windows XP system and discovered that in Explorer, its name was changed from `My Passport` to `Local Disk K` which shows 0 KB and is inaccessible.

When I double click it, it shows an error message

> Drive is corrupted or inaccessible

When I tried connecting my HDD to Ubuntu, it works perfectly fine. What could that be, and how can I solve this?

Comment: what is the file system type for the drive? while its hooked to your linux system, run 'mount' and make note of the "Type".

Comment: i guess its fuseblk..as its showing following :"/dev/sdb1 on /media/My Passport type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)"

Comment: That's a [filesystem in user space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), could be NTFS.

Comment: interesting, I've not see that one. ok, try 'sudo fdisk -l' to list your drives and partions.

Answer (score 1):

The fault is with the partition table on your external hard drive. You can fix it by doing the following:

1. Open an elevated command prompt (Start menu → type `cmd` → hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Type in the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   chkdsk E:
   ```

   Replace `E:` with the letter of the drive you want to check.
3. After it finishes and gives you a report on bad sectors, retype the command, but add the `/F` switch:

   ```
   chkdsk E: /F
   ```

That should fix it. It took about 30 minutes for me, and when the process was done my files were still there.

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly to fix the partition table?

Comment: +1....please tell me how to fix the partition table on eternal hdd

Comment: This worked for me, open command prompt in admin mode. Then type chkdsk e: e being drive or what ever your is. After it gives report of bad sectors retype previous command add /f. Should solve problem let me know.